# Pasta Static sem compilar no vue-cli e poder trocar os valores dela menualmente após publicado

Tags: vue.js

Tenho um site em vueJS que eu publico em cada cliente meu. este site consome endpoints.
Para o cliente A eu tenho www.clienteA.com.br/endpoint/api
Para o cliente B eu tenho www.clienteB.com.br/endpoint/api
O que eu fiz e não deu certo:

1. Arquivo JSON

Criei um arquivo JSON no diretório static que tem
{ endpoint: ""}

2. Service HTTP
   no meus serviceshttp eu leio esse json para pegar a url correta.
3. Build site
   dou um build no site
   O build é através du vue-cli
4. Alterando Json após publicado
   pego a pasta static e altero a url para cada cliente inicialmente na mão mesmo.

**Erro**

Pelo que estou vendo qdo dou um build ele pega os valores desse JSON e injeta no meu código então não adiata após o build eu alterar o valor.

Tem alguma forma de eu fazer isso?

Comment: É só a URL que troca? Eu faria usando variáveis de ambiente, você teria um .env.clientea um .env.clienteb  com as respectivas urls de cada cliente, de uma olhada em https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/mode-and-env.html#modes

Comment: mas eu teria que compilar a cada alteração. A ideia era deixa num json e eu pegaria o publicado e só trocava o conteúdo do json. tudo que percebi qdo faço isso é que o json está sendo compilado junto e eu não queria, Minha idéia era ler o json durante o uso do site

Comment: como voce esta chamando esse json? pra ele estar sendo adicionando no bundle no meio do js vc deve estar fazendo import nele.

Comment: nas na verdade oq vc tem que fazer é uma request, com o fetch ou axios. ai depende de como vc esta tratando isso.